# How to check if an element is to the right of another in android espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to check if an element is to the right of another element using espresso. How to check it. A sample example would be helpful

```
ViewInteraction textView = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.name), withText("dín"), childAtPosition(childAtPosition(IsInstanceOf.<View>instanceOf(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.class), 0), 0), isDisplayed()));
```

The text din should appear right to another text which is to the left

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/LayoutTest.java - google sample test app has samples of positionassertion, which is what you need

Answer (score 3):

[PositionAssertions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/assertion/PositionAssertions) help you test the relative location of elements on the screen(on xy plane, z plane is ignored).

Here is sample documentation taken from [google testing sample app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/LayoutTest.java)

```
 public void testRelativePositions() {
    // left text should be left of right button although they share 1 pixel at the boundary.
    onView(withId(R.id.left_text)).check(isLeftOf(withId(R.id.right_button)));
    // Switch length button should be above Wrap button
    onView(withId(R.id.length)).check(isAbove(withId(R.id.wrap)));
    // Switch length button and Wrap button should be aligned to the left.
     onView(withId(R.id.length)).check(isLeftAlignedWith(withId(R.id.wrap)));
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to check something like the below? Because the id is common `onView(allOf(withId(R.id.stv_left),withText("Electricity"),check(isLeftOf(withId(R.id.right_button)));`

Comment: ? how ar the id's common? they're clearly different

Comment: i mean it's a recyclerview and it has categories displayed, so the category names doesnt have different id's. That's why i asked if we can verify additionally with text.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to get it to work with the below code

```
   ViewInteraction textView = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.name), withText("ble"), childAtPosition(childAtPosition(IsInstanceOf.<View>instanceOf(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.class), 0), 0), isDisplayed()));
        textView.check(matches(withText("ble")));
        textView.check(isCompletelyRightOf(withId(R.id.menu_level1)));
```